# How to paste a snapshot to an org file(emacs) on windows

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I love to use org mode to take notes. I want following steps to paste a snapshot to an org file on Windows.

1. Press the PrtSC to take a snapshot
2. Open an org file using emacs and press Ctrl+Y to paste the snapshot.
3. the snapshot automatic save as the jpg file to the disk, and its link write to that org file.

How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean with a snapshot? A [screenshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot)?

Answer (score 1):

FYI here's a solution for Linux. Not much help for Windows, but maybe it'll spur some ideas.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/33770